# Is there a way to set a list to a models type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, datamodel

I have a method that is using generics, so the developer can enter in a model of their choice which can be any type (user, employer, ...) these are all custom classes.

I want to make a list of this type.

Something like this:

```
Public void makeList<T>(IEnumerable<T> model){
  List<model.getType()> list = new List<model.getType()>
}
```

EDIT:
Clarification:
lets say This method was an action, If I wanted to call this action from a view and return a result, but wanted to pass an arbitrary model. I know that Actions cannot use generics.

Can we do something like

```
Public void makeList(IEnumerable<Dynamic> model){
  List<model.getType()> list = new List<model.getType()>
}
```

Since this is an action

Answer (score 3):

maybe you need

```
List<T> list = new List<T>();
```

Answer (score 1):

`T` represents the type

```
 Public void makeList<T>(IEnumerable<T> model){
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are really don't understand what you doing. I suppose you method should look like this:

```
public void makeList<T>(IEnumerable<T> model)
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>(model);
}
```

You don't need to get model type becouse it's [generic method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx) and `T` will be changed with your type at compile time for all cases. This line:

```
new List<T>(model)
```

Only need to init your `List<T>` with `IEnumerable<T>` that comes to method.